# Find mapping between ASCII values in C

Tags: c

I'm stuck at this problem. I want to take in a char as input (ex: a) and return h. And b would return p. c would x. I am to use the ASCII table to figure out the bitwise mapping between the characters. Any help would be appreciated. The question says "For the two suggested input texts, use the table of ASCII codes to identify the bitwise mapping between input and outputs." So I need to look at the ASCII table binary representation of the values and find a pattern that is common in all of them

So in short:

```
input : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
output: hpxaiqybjrzcksf{dlt|emu}gfnv
```

This is the skeleton of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int inChar, outChar;

    while((inChar = getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        //your code here

        //last statement in while loop
        putchar(outChar);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need bits or the ASCII table find the input char in the first string and output the char in the same position from the second string.

Comment: @stark I'm not sure what you mean by "output the char in the same position from the second string". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: So, you want something like: `while (1) { int ichr = getc(stdin); if (ichr == EOF) break; int ochr = xlat[(unsigned char) ichr]; fputc(ochr,stdout); }`. And, you want to init `xlat` with: `unsigned char xlat[256] = { ['a'] = 'h', ['b'] = 'p', ['c'] = 'x', ... };` ???

Comment: @CraigEstey ahh i see. I was looking for a more "logical" approach. To see a pattern between the characters and come up with a single algorithms that works for all of them

Comment: Based on your given translation, you _don't_ have something that can do `ochr = xlatfunc(ichr)` such as: `ochr = (ichr + 27) % 256;` The easiest/fastest way is a translation table.

Comment: freakPie225, Why are the input and output strings of different length?  This is a _mapping between the characters_.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the ASCII representations of the letters and their mappings in binary? (Or just their position in the alphabet - a=1, b=2 etc.) If you do that you should see a pattern very quickly after the first few letters...

Comment: Solution is available here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142099/find-mapping-between-ascii-values-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Working with that skeleton, if you can only put code inside the loop, then just compute the character looking at the string every single time. This is very slow but gets the job done, there really is no other good way if you cannot put code outside the loop.

There you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int inChar, outChar;

    while((inChar = getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        char *in  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char *out = "hpxaiqybjrzcksf{dlt|emu}gfnv";
        char *match;

        match = strchr(in, inChar);

        if (match == NULL)
            outChar = '?'; // Some default char in case nothing matches.
        else
            outChar = out[match - in];

        putchar(outChar);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a link to [`strchr()` documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) in case you are not familiar with the function.

---

Old answer, efficient way of solving the problem.

Just use a simple array as a map for the characters:

```
int main(void) {
    // Empty map (all '\0' characters).
    char map[256] = {0};

    // Original characters:
    char *in_chars  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    // Corresponding translated characters:
    char *out_chars = "hpxaiqybjrzcksf{dlt|emu}gfnv";

    int i;

    // Assign each character from in_chars the corresponding one 
    // from out_chars by adding it to the map.
    for (i = 0; in_chars[i] != '\0' && out_chars[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char from = in_chars[i];
        char to = out_chars[i];
        map[from] = to;
    }

    while (1) {
        // Get one character from standard input:
        int c = getchar();

        // Break the loop in case of error or end of input:
        if (c == EOF) 
            break;

        // Convert the input character to the corresponding output
        // character according to the map, and output it:             
        putchar(map[c]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Characters that don't appear in `in_chars` will be replaced with `\0`. You can do an initial `memset()` to set the default value to something else if you want.

Also, the two strings you provided are of different lengths, you might want to check that.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't understand this at all (I'm a beginner in C). I'm pretty sure I'm only supposed to use Bitwise operators as we haven't gone over pointers just yet. 

As for the strings, I just noticed that, yes. But that's what the question says

Comment: This is similar to what I would do [was going to do], but it needs some clarification [from OP] because `out_chars` is larger than `in_chars`. As it is, `*p` will run beyond the end of `in_chars` [i.e. UB]

Comment: @CraigEstey no it won't.

Comment: `while (*p && *q)
        map[*p++] = *q++;` relies on `*p` being non-negative.  True in this case and for ASCII, but not in general .  Consider `map[(unsigned char) *p++]`.  Also `char map[256]` --> `unsigned char map[256]`

Comment: To be more clear, the question says "For the suggested input text, use the table of ASCII codes to identify the bitwise mapping between input and outputs."

Comment: @freakPie225 that's exactly what I am doing. Construct a mapping between the characters and then use it. I will edit the code to make it more clear and simpler to understand, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct (_not_ UB), but `nv` will not be used from `out_chars`. So, we should mention that the string lengths should be equal.

Comment: @freakPie225 updated the code, see it you find it clearer now.

Comment: The skeleton of the code is:
``````
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int inChar, outChar;
    
    while((inChar = getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        //your code here

        //last statement in while loop
        putchar(outChar);
    }
    return 0;
}
````````

Comment: @freakPie225 you should have *definitely* mentioned that in the question. Edit it. Also, you need stuff out of the loop unless you want to re-create the map every single time or unless you want to write a very, very long `switch` statement with cases for every character. Only putting code inside the loop doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the question now. Also I'm strictly told not to add any code to the provided skeleton apart from the commented part

Comment: @MarcoBonelli that does make sense, but is there no way to do this on a binary level? Like a = 01100001 and h = 01101000. Similarly, b = 01100010 and p = 0111100. I think I have to see a pattern there because the question says "Important: Leave the current code stub unchanged.  The additional code should appear in the region indicated by the comment field. Do not introduce other `loop' structures"

Comment: @freakPie225 if you keep adding one piece of information after the other I will not be able to help you, I cannot unfortunately read your mind. Yes, it can be done without another loop, you can substitute the `for` loop in my solution with the `strchr()` function to check where the character is positioned inside the first string. No, it cannot be done using stuff "on binary level". It's a substitution cypher, there really is nothing much more to do than the two solutions I've showed you.

Comment: I did mention in the question that I'm supposed to use the ASCII table to figure out the mapping. But I suppose you're right, I am absolutely failing to see a single pattern between those characters

Comment: @freakPie225 "use the ASCII table" doesn't mean anything really. A character has a value, that value is dictated by the ASCII table. You don't "use" the ASCII table, the table simply defines the value of each character.

Comment: @freakPie225 I've updated my answer to not use any additional loop. I will not be editing any further. Good luck with your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 bool IsBitSet(int b, int pos)
 {​​​​​​
      return (b & (1 << pos)) != 0;
 }​​​​​​

 int SetBit(int value, int bitToSet)
 {​​​​​​
     return value | (int)pow(2, bitToSet);
 }​​​​​​

 int ClearBit(int value, int bitToClear)
 {​​​​​​
     return (value & ~((int)pow(2, bitToClear)));
 }​​​​​​

int main(void)
{​​​​​​
      unsigned char inChar= 0, outChar=0;
      while ((inChar = getchar()) != EOF)
{​​​​​​
// Your bitwise code appears here…
char isFirstBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 0);
char isSecondBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 1);
char isFourthBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 3);
char isFifthBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 4);

// If first bit is set
if (isFirstBitset)
{​​​​​​
    inChar = SetBit(inChar, 3);
    if (!isFourthBitset)
        inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 0);
}​​​​​​

// If 2nd bit is set
if (isSecondBitset)
{​​​​​​
    inChar = SetBit(inChar, 4);
    if (!isFifthBitset)
        inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 1);
}​​​​​​

// if 4th bit is set
if (isFourthBitset)
{​​​​​​
    inChar = SetBit(inChar, 0);
    if (!isFirstBitset)
        inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 3);
}​​​​​​

// if 5th bit is set
if (isFifthBitset)
{​​​​​​
    inChar = SetBit(inChar, 1);
    if (!isSecondBitset)
        inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 4);
}​​​​​​

outChar = inChar;
putchar(outChar);
 }​​​​​​
 return 0;
   }​​​​​​
```